# Transfer Rails App from Heroku to OpsWorks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, aws-opsworks

I want to switch from heroku to opsworks with my Rails App, but I ran into trouble with that.
My App uses Rails 4.0.4 and Ruby 2.0.0 on a single Ubuntu 12.04 LTS t1.micro instance.
My Idea is to run the app on a rails layer in OpsWorks and to use RDS (Postgres) for my database.

So when I start an instance and deploy my app everything seems fine and the bundler installs all gems successfully.

But when I try to reach the app by the IP-Adress in browser it takes minutes for the server to  respond to my request and it ends in a "We're sorry, but something went wrong." message.

I've also tried to get the log data from rails, but unfortunately the log/production.rb in the app's directory is empty.

Would be helpful if someone can provide <strike>a way how I can see the log-files or</strike> a way how to deploy a Rails app on OpsWorks with postgres database on RDS.

Iam only using "libpq-dev" as custom OS-Package and custom JSON, all other settings are default values.

**[Update]**

Found the correct log-file at `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

Server fails to connect to my RDS-Database

```
{
  "deploy": {
    "app_name": {
      "database" : {
        "adapter" : "postgresql",
        "database" : "database",
        "username" : "db_user",
        "password" : "password",
        "host" : "xyz.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com",
        "port" : "5432"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the answer to my problem at this how-to: [http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2013/09/using-aws-elasticache-for-redis-with-aws-opsworks.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+AmazonWebServicesBlog+(Amazon+Web+Services+Blog)](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2013/09/using-aws-elasticache-for-redis-with-aws-opsworks.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+AmazonWebServicesBlog+%28Amazon+Web+Services+Blog%29)

Using the same default-Security Group for RDS and OpsWorks instances makes it.